# Why didn't EDITH recognise Mysterio and inform Peter?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home* (2019), Peter transfers [E.D.I.T.H.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/E.D.I.T.H.) to Quentin Beck.

But why didn’t E.D.I.T.H. recognise Quentin, who was a former employee under Tony Stark?

So why didn’t E.D.I.T.H. inform Peter that Mysterio is actually a former Stark industries employee who was fired by Stark and not some guy from another Earth?

Comment: the movie would be very short then

Comment: Does Peter even wear the glasses around Beck? I don't think he does. Even during the scene when Peter gives Beck the glasses, I don't think he actually wore them. They were just sitting on the counter, until Beck put them on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why didn't EDITH recognise Quentin, who was a former employee under Tony Stark?

### We don't know...

However, your question assumes that EDITH had access to this information. Insofar as EDITH was intended for Peter's use there's no particular reason why she should have lists of ex-employees on hand. There must be *some* limits to the amount of information she has on hand.

> Why didn't EDITH inform Peter that Mysterio is actually a former Stark industries employee who was fired by Stark and not some guy from another Earth?

Given the above and even assuming that she did recognise Beck he's *supposedly* from **another Earth**.

There's no reason why there couldn't be a Quentin Beck on this Earth AND another (Mysterio) on another Earth.

So even if she did recognise him, he has an easy explanation that he's a DIFFERENT Quentin Beck.

Comment: eh I don't buy either of those explanations. Those are flimsy at best. 1) We know all Stark tech does facial recognition on site, and we even see EDITH do this when he puts the glasses on and starts providing way more information than basic identity (i.e. text messages that are currently being typed). 2) In a multiverse, yes there would be a duplicate Quentin Beck, but EDITH is an extremely advanced AI and it should be her duty to at least identify his Earth identity. At minimum, EDITH wouldn't know about alternate Earths and mistakenly flag him if we really want to say EDITH "isn't capable".

Comment: Before Far from home there was no mention of Alternate Earths, so there's no reason that Tony Would take alternate Earth duplicates into account when programming EDITH, now we know that these virtual assistants are some form of AI and that they are capable of self learning but we know that they have their limits, remeber when one of the suits tagged Pepper as a threat by accident in Iron Man 3, I guess the best explanation for this is that the script writers goofed up.

Comment: @searchengine27 if you critically analyze all movies to be perfectly realistic you'll find they all have some fairly flimsy explanations as to how something can or can't be done

Comment: @BKlassen nobody is saying that there are always great explanations for movie magic, but just saying "because its movie magic makes all explanations reasonable" is some false logic, specifically [False Dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) (among at least 1 or 2 other fallacies). I'm saying in the spectrum of explanations that are plausible, this is pretty close to the bottom of the list. The Marvel movies aim to place themselves within the realm of 'possible', meaning the explanation must also be reasonably possible - which this explanation is not.

Answer (score 31):

## Peter Never Asked

Its been a little while since I watched Far From Home, but I can't recall any instance where EDITH volunteered information without Peter (or Beck) directly asking for it. EDITH isn't a Jarvis-level AI, it doesn't have the intuition to listen and understand the context well enough to know that a ruse is in the works.

If Peter had ever asked EDITH to search for facial recognition matches on Beck, he almost certainly would have been presented with Beck's Stark Employee persona, although, as @Paulie_D points out, they may have just chalked it up to multi-dimensional trickery

Comment: F.R.I.D.A.Y. and J.A.R.V.I.S. are described as a "natural-language user interface".  [E.D.I.T.H.](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/E.D.I.T.H.) is an "augmented reality security, defense and artificial tactical intelligence" and "provides several backdoor entrances to some of the world's largest telecommunications companies giving the user access to all of the target's personal information" - all you'd have to do is spoof the telecom information.

Comment: Peter never asked, and she wouldn't know. Naming a third AI kinda gave it away: it can't possibly do anything that Jarvis couldn't, because there wasn't anything he couldn't do. Basically Edith gives you access to some satellites and the internet; Jarvis is too busy being a corporeal demigod.

Comment: @Mazura There is plenty JARVIS can't do, even in the MCU. It couldn't hack into War Machine during the chase at the Stark Expo in Iron Man 2. It also couldn't contain Ultron in Avengers 2. And after Avengers 2, JARVIS can't do anything at all, because it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Isn't there a scene where Jarvis does some *Person of Interest* / Batman-cellphone-surveillance level hacking? ... 'Back doors'? Jarvis had the keys to the *front* doors. IMO, Edith's touted abilities wouldn't even be on Jarvis' CV; those are a given.