# Why didn't Peter use EDITH against the fight with the fire monster?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-far-from-home

Peter Parker had a multi billion dollar defence system available to him but did not use it in the fight against the fire monster *Spider-Man: Far From Home*. Why is this?

Comment: Orbital airstrikes are generally frowned upon in populated areas. He was kinda on tilt after almost killing everyone on that bridge.

Comment: Here's, these glasses things, that aren't going to be useful to you and aren't as good as their predecessors, and therefor are obviously only a plot coupon for the antagonist. : [Why didn't EDITH recognise Mysterio and inform Peter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/107173/8580)

Comment: *Even Dead I'm Totally Hubristic* - that's why he (or the writers, rather) gave him Edith instead of Friday, who would've made the entire plot moot; on several occasions we've seen self-aware AI save the day. The real question is why Tony gave him third-rate AI that controls a multi-billion dollar defense system that uses substandard safety protocols.